# Entering complex data structures in SpecFlow tables

Tags: c#, specflow

I have something like the following complex data structure that I need to load into my SpecFlow tests:

```cs
public Album {
    public string Title;
    public float RunTime;
    public List<Track> Tracks;
}

public Track {
    public string Title;
    public float RunTime;
}
```

Currently I'm using a single table to add all this data, with one row per track:

```gherkin
AlbumTitle | 10.00 | Track1Title | 2.00
AlbumTitle | 10.00 | Track2Title | 2.00
AlbumTitle | 10.00 | Track3Title | 3.00
AlbumTitle | 10.00 | Track4Title | 3.00
```

For my actual dataset, this results in an overly long table (t least 9 columns) that's difficult to read, not to mention the repetition problem for the parent class data.

Is there a way to pass two tables into a SpecFlow step, or is there a better way to pass in data structues like this?

---

### Edit

A more accurate (and therefore complicated) toy model for my problem is

```cs
public Policy {
    public string Number;
    public string CustomerId;
    public string Type;
    public DateTime Start;
    public DateTime End;
    public List<InsuredObject> InsuredObjects;
}
public InsuredObject {
    public string Type;
    public List<Cover> Covers;
}
public Covers {
    public string Type;
    public string Deductible;
    public DateTime ValidFrom;
    public DateTime ValidTo;
}
```

which we populate with

```
| Policy.Number | Policy.Type | Policy.CustomerNumber | InsuredObject.Type | Cover.Type | Cover.Deductible | Policy.ValidFrom | Cover.ValidTo   | Cover.ValidFrom | Cover.ValidTo |
| 1345678       | Home        | 87654321              | House              | Theft      | 130              | 2022-01-01       | 2022-12-31      | 2022-01-01      | 2022-06-01    |
| 1345678       | Home        | 87654321              | House              | Fire       | 130              | 2022-01-01       | 2022-12-31      | 2022-01-01      | 2022-12-31    |
```

generating a single Policy containing a single InsuredObject with two Cover objects

Comment: You could consider simple markup like JSON or YAML that is supplied to the steps as a simple (albeit long) string and then parsed, or as a supplemental file (`given the album "samplealbum.json"`). Alternatively, describe things in business language instead -- this is often possible because you don't *really* care about the *exact* contents of all fields. For example, you could have `given an album with tracks with runtimes "2, 2, 3, 3" when I ask for the album runtime then the total runtime should be 10`, leaving the exact setup logic to the step implementation.

Comment: As an aside, a `float` is a poor choice for a duration, given the accuracy issues when calculating totals. Consider `TimeSpan`, `decimal` or just `int` with `RuntimeInSeconds` or suchlike. `TimeSpan` allows for especially easy parsing.

Comment: Can you [edit] you question to include the full step that has 9 columns? It is difficult to answer your question without seeing the data your step is working with.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for then suggestions. The string/file solution isn't doesn't feel good, especially since we're likely to end up with hundreds of tests, requiring a variety of these objects, either we'll expand the feature file with too much text, or obscure the test data in a bunch of files.
We're trying something like the business language approach for now, with some inline fields as well as a table for the child objects.

The Album is just a toy model that fits the general shape of my problem. I'll edit the question to also include a more suitable model

Comment: When you've got complex objects like these it's especially important that tests remain readable, in the sense that you should ideally only mention what's relevant without including what's *not* relevant because it's internal to the system (like the policy number, or the customer number). Things like dates are probably also only worth mentioning in the form "which is still valid" or "with coverage that has expired", with those descriptions generating dates on the fly. Of course a balance has to be struck to ensure steps are not too "magical" (they must not need tests themselves).

Comment: If all that still leaves you with tables, you still have many options -- there's no rule that you can only use one table. So you can have something like `given a policy named "X" <table> and "X" has insured objects <table with objects and covers>`, which you can split however it makes most sense. Specflow is almost endlessly flexible when it comes to specifying test cases, and if possible you should start from "how would an actual insuring agent/user of the system describe it". Don't be afraid to involve non-coders, they often have great ideas -- when they're not being scared off by code. :)

Comment: That is better, but it is unclear which columns map to which entities. Can you [edit] your question to include that information?

Comment: @JeroenMostert I've been working on trying to simplify the test data, including removing those identifiers as you suggested. I *think* I've got it down to a few inline variables and a single table, but I'm interested in how you can compose a step with multiple tables. Could you share an example of how that looks in Gherkin?

Comment: I can't unless you can provide a mapping of columns to entities in your question. Knowing that is the crux of providing you with an example.

Comment: In a single scenario you can have as many steps as you want of the form `Given/And that Widget "X" is` followed by a table, which are then implemented as `GivenThatWidgetIs(string x, Table table)`. Linking up structures could be done implicitly by order or explicitly by name; the former is of course a little more fragile and requires keeping state.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Ok, thanks. I was hoping there was some magic syntax that allows multiple tables in a single step. I don't like the idea of fragmenting this arrangement into different steps, if I can help it, but this discussion has helped me to revise the step down to actually relevant data.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I've cheanged the data table column headers to match the `object.member` format. Hopefully that makes the mapping more obvious.

Comment: The main USP of a Specflow test is to be readable by anyone with sufficient domain knowledge, so if that means a scenario has to be split into a bunch of different steps to convey the context that's not a problem in and of itself -- such steps themselves don't "do" anything and there's no tax on them. If having a very compact or structured way for presenting the input data is a higher priority than having the test as readable natural language, you could always consider not using Specflow (or at least not for those parts), or having the data itself external.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you are providing one giant data table for many entities. Scenarios would look something like:

```
Scenario: ...
    Given some really big data table:
        | Policy.Number | Policy.Type | Policy.CustomerNumber | InsuredObject.Type | Cover.Type | Cover.Deductible | Policy.ValidFrom | Cover.ValidTo   | Cover.ValidFrom | Cover.ValidTo |
        | 1345678       | Home        | 87654321              | House              | Theft      | 130              | 2022-01-01       | 2022-12-31      | 2022-01-01      | 2022-06-01    |
        | 1345678       | Home        | 87654321              | House              | Fire       | 130              | 2022-01-01       | 2022-12-31      | 2022-01-01      | 2022-12-31    |
    When ...
    Then ...
```

While this results in fewer lines of gherkin to read, it is not *readable*, because the data table is so wide. Instead, you want to decompose this data table into one step per entity.

Before I begin, I am making the assumption that the policy number and customer number is assigned by the software system. If these numbers do not have relevant domain concepts associated with them, then there is no need to mention them in the scenario. Step definitions should handle connecting these entities together behind the scenes.

You actually have 4 entities (one of which you did not mention in your question, but certainly exists as a domain concept for the business):

- The **customer** (not mentioned in your question, but likely exists)
- The **insurance policy**
- The **object being insured**
- The **types of coverage** for the object being insured

Consider writing one step for each entity. This allows for a clear and concise setup for the data in your scenario:

```
Scenario: ...
    Given "Helen" is a customer
    And "Helen" has a  "Home" policy valid from "2022-01-01" to "2022-12-31"
    And the "Home" policy for "Helen" insures a "House"
    And the "Home" policy for "Helen" covers her "House" for:
        | Coverage Type | Deductible | Valid From | Valid To   |
        | Theft         | 130        | 2022-01-01 | 2022-06-01 |
        | Fire          | 130        | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31 |
    When ...
    Then ...
```

As I mentioned earlier, there is no mention of a policy number or customer number. Instead, provide names for things. Here, `Given "Helen" is a customer` will create a new customer. This step definition should then track the customer number created for "Helen" so that other steps can dynamically access Helen's customer number by her name (see [Context Injection](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Sharing-Data-between-Bindings.html#context-injection)).

Likewise, the step `Given "Helen" has a  "Home" policy...` will get the customer number based on the person's name, and create an insurance policy. Assuming the system generates the policy number, this step should associate this dynamic policy number with "Helen" and the "Home" policy.

Finally, the only sensible use for a data table is defining the kinds of coverage for Helen's home insurance. This is legitimately a list of things. The step `Given the "Home" policy for "Helen" covers her "House" for:` works well with a data table, because each row has a small enough number of columns that the step remains easy to read and understand.

This requires some setup though. Specifically, you will want to understand [context injection](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Sharing-Data-between-Bindings.html#context-injection).

1. Create your test context class, which is a holder for test data:

   ```
   public class InsuranceTestContext
   {
       private readonly Dictionary<string, Customer> customers;
       private readonly Dictionary<string, List<InsurancePolicy>> policies;

       public InsuranceTestContext()
       {
           customers = new Dictionary<string, Customer>();
           policies = new Dictionary<string, List<InsurancePolicy>>();
       }

       public void AddCustomer(string customerName, Customer customer)
       {
           customers[customerName] = customer;
       }

       public void AddPolicy(string customerNumber, InsurancePolicy policy)
       {
           if (!policies.ContainsKey(customerNumber))
           {
               policies[customerNumber] = new List<InsurancePolicy>();
           }

           policies[customerNumber].Add(policy);
       }

       public Customer GetCustomer(string customerName)
       {
           return customers[customerName];
       }

       public InsurancePolicy GetPolicy(string customerNumber, string policyType)
       {
           return policies[customerNumber].Single(p => p.PolicyType == policyType);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Register a new instance of `InsuranceTestContext` with the SpecFlow dependency injection framework. I usually do this in a dedicated "hooks" class:

   ```
   [Binding]
   public class Hooks
   {
       private readonly IObjectContainer container;

       public Hooks(IObjectContainer container)
       {
           this.container = container;
       }

       [BeforeScenario]
       public void CreateTestContext()
       {
           var testContext = new InsuranceTestContext();

           container.RegisterInstanceAs(testContext);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create a class to represent each row in the data table defined in the 4th step (you will need this in a step definition):

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// Represents a row in a SpecFlow datatable describing insurace coverage
   /// </summary>
   public class CoverageTypeDataRow
   {
       public string CoverageType { get; set; }
       public decimal Deductible { get; set; }
       public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
       public DateTime ValidTo { get; set; }
   }
   ```
4. Glue everything together in your step definition class:

   ```
   [Binding]
   public class CustomerSteps
   {
       private readoly InsuranceTestContext testContext;

       public CustomerSteps(InsuranceTestContext testContext)
       {
           this.testContext = testContext;
       }

       [Given(@"""(.*)"" is a customer")]
       public void GivenIsACustomer(string customerName)
       {
           var customer = // create customer however you normally create it

           testContext.AddCustomer(customerName, customer);
       }

       [Given(@"""(.*)"" has a ""(.*)"" policy valid from ""(.*)"" to ""(.*)""")]
       public void HasAPolicyValidFromTo(string customerName, string policyType, DateTime validFrom, DateTime validTo)
       {
           var customer = testContext.GetCustomer(customerName);
           var policy = // create policy however you normally create it (using customerNumber, policyType, validFrom and validTo)

           testContext.AddPolicy(customerNumber, policy);
       }

       [Given(@"the ""(.*)"" policy for ""(.*)"" insures an? ""(.*)""")]
       public void ThePolicyForInsuresA(string policyType, string customerName, string insuredObjectType)
       {
           var customer = testContext.GetCustomer(customerName);
           var policy = testContext.GetPolicy(customerNumber, policyType);
           var insuredObject = // create this based on customer, policy, insuredObjectType

           // This will depend on your entity API
           policy.InsuredObjects.Add(insuredObject);
       }

       [Given(@"the ""(.*)"" policy for ""(.*)"" covers ([^ ]+) ""(.*)"" for:")]
       public void ThePolicyForCoversFor(string policyType, string customerName, string pronoun, string insuredObjectType, Table table)
       {
           var customer = testContext.GetCustomer(customerName);
           var policy = testContext.GetPolicy(customer.CustomerNumber, policyType);
           var insuredObject = policy.InsuredObjects.Single(i => i.Type == insuredObjectType);
           var coverageTypesToAdd = table.CreateSet<CoverageTypeDataRow>();

           foreach (var coverage in coverageTypesToAdd)
           {
               // This will depend on your entity API
               insuredObject.AddCoverage(/* add using coverage.CoverageType, coverage.Deductible, coverage.ValidFrom and coverage.ValidTo */);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

**Important:** I left out some technical details, like data access. This gives you the basic scaffolding required, but your specific entity API, including other calls to repositories or web services, has been left out. This can be pretty involved, and is entirely dependent on your application.